# Question "smell"

Tags: discussion, flagging

This question - [Power of 2 and performance in SQL Server](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246034/power-of-2-and-performance-in-sql-server) - is this a "good" question by the standards of this site?  Sure, it's an advanced optimisation programming technique.  But my first response was "so what"?  Either my application needs to divide by 255 or it needs to divide by 256.  It's not like I'm *not* going to use SQL Server for that one query in my applicaiton and install a customised MariaDB instance to save a few nanoseconds.

I thought about flagging it.  "It should be closed for another reason" was the only option which made sense.  "Too broad" it diametrically opposite to what it is and nothing under "off topic" matched my concerns.

It *is* interesting, but its not "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" IMHO. Guidance, please?

Answer (score 4):

I had to think about this one a bit.

Practical and answerable?  Perhaps it is because the OP is likely asking trying to figure out how to squeeze performance out of SQL Server in low level mathematical operations.  The question is intriguing to me to but then I am particularly fond of questions that concern strategies in tuning an application.

In all, I am probably biased because I honestly WANT TO KNOW the answer to this question :)

I wouldn't personally close it, but I would support a fellow mod that felt the need to or the community if they chose to close it.